# How to set unique at struct Beego

Tags: go, orm, controller, mariadb, beego

How to set unique at the struct specific columns. first name

```
type User struct {
  ID              int64     `orm:"size(100)", pk`
  Lastname        string    `orm:"size(100)"`
  Firstname       string    `orm:"size(100)"`
  Role            string    `orm:"size(100)"`
  Created         time.Time `orm:"size(100)"`
  Updated         time.Time `orm:"size(100)"`
}
```

I'm using `"github.com/astaxie/beego/orm"`

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/models.md#unique), you just add the word "unique" to the tag:

> Add unique key for one field
>
> ```
> Name string `orm:"unique"`
> ```

To combine tags, you must use a semicolon as documented [here](https://beego.me/docs/mvc/model/models.md#set-parameters).  For example:

```
Firstname string orm:"unique;size(100)"
```

Comment: `<snide-remark>`With 3rd party connections to MySQL, you are stuck with learning about _both_.`</snide-remark>`.  What's with a "time" that is "size 100"??

Comment: @RickJames: A question for the asker, not the answerer :)